# Tips to Handle Collisions

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, konvajs

I am trying to create a konva canvas where shapes are draggable, are kept within the bounds of the canvas and also don't overlap, so if a collision is detected then I need to handle this somehow. I've managed to get the first 2 working but can't handle collision detection properly.

I am able to detect collisions fine in realtime and 50% of the time handle this as I wish, get them to bounce back on x or y axis -20 or +20 depending on the direction of the drag but the other 50% of the time I am getting my shapes laying on top of each other which is what I am trying to avoid and then the shapes seem to stop receiving events altogether (they no longer highlight even which is in mouseover and mouseout).

I will add my code but I suppose I am looking for a little advice on how I should handle the collision as I don't think my approach is the best (I still have to think about what if there is another shape colliding when bumped over) but should I be bumping over x or y +20/-20 when I detect a collision? It does seem nice behaviour when it works and also how best to work out which axis I should be adjusting - can my approach to detecting drag direction be improved? (as I really think this is what is causing the shapes to sometimes overlap and become unresponsive)

Thank you for any advice you can offer. I have only provided the relevant code (as that's enough!) which is part of the dragFunc for the shape and then the function to detect collisions.

```
function intersectRect( a,  b) {
 if (a.x() < b.x + b.width  && a.x() + a.width()  > b.x &&
    a.y() < b.y + b.height && a.y() + a.height() > b.y) {
        console.log("COLLISION!!!");
        return true;
}
else{
    console.log("NO COLLISION!!!");
    return false;
}
    }

function theDragFunc(pos) {
var thisRect;
if(parseInt(this.getClientRect().width) != parseInt(this.width())){
if(userRotation == 90 || userRotation == 270)
thisRect = {x: this.x(), y: this.y(), width: this.getClientRect().height, height: this.getClientRect().width};
else
thisRect = {x: this.x(), y: this.y(), width: this.getClientRect().width, height: this.getClientRect().height};
console.log("must have changed userRotation="+userRotation);
}
else{
thisRect = {x: this.x(), y: this.y(), width: this.width(), height: this.height()};
//console.log("must not have changed userRotation="+userRotation);
}

var isCollision = false;
for(var i=0; i < shapes.length; i++) {


    var a = shapes[i];
    var b = thisRect;
    if((a.x() === thisRect.x) && (a.y() === thisRect.y) && (a.width() === thisRect.width) && (a.height() === thisRect.height))
    {
        console.log("this is the same item");

    }
    else
    {
    isCollision =intersectRect(shapes[i], thisRect);
    if(isCollision)
    break;
    }
}


    if(isCollision)
    {
    var newX = 0;
    var newY = 0
    console.log("pointer x was "+startPointX + " and is now" + stage.getPointerPosition().x);
    console.log("pointer y was"+startPointY + " and is now " + stage.getPointerPosition().y);
    var threshold = 5;
    var restraint = 5;
   var distX =  startPointX  >  stage.getPointerPosition().x  ? startPointX  -  stage.getPointerPosition().x :     stage.getPointerPosition().x - startPointX;// get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
    var distY =  startPointY  >  stage.getPointerPosition().y  ? startPointY  -  stage.getPointerPosition().y :     stage.getPointerPosition().y - startPointY;// get horizontal dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
     var swipedir = "nodirection";
    if (distX > distY && distX > 1){ // 2nd condition for horizontal swipe met
            swipedir = stage.getPointerPosition().x  < startPointX ? 'left' : 'right' ;// if dist traveled is negative, it indicates left swipe
        }
        else if (distY > distX && distY > 1){ // 2nd condition for vertical swipe met
            swipedir = stage.getPointerPosition().y  < startPointY ? 'up' : 'down'; // if dist traveled is negative, it indicates up swipe
        }

console.log("swipedir = "+ swipedir);
if(swipedir == "left")
{
    newX = thisRect.x +10;
    startPointX = newX;
    newY = thisRect.y;
    startPointY = newY;
}
else if(swipedir == "right")
{
    newX = thisRect.x -10;
        startPointX = newX;
    newY = thisRect.y;
        startPointY = newY;
}
else if(swipedir == "up")
{
    newX = thisRect.x ;
        startPointX = newX;
    newY = thisRect.y + 10; 
    startPointY = newY;
}
else if(swipedir == "down")
{
    newX = thisRect.x ;
        startPointX = newX;
    newY = thisRect.y - 10;
        startPointY = newY;
}
else
{
        newX = thisRect.x ;
            startPointX = newX;
    newY = thisRect.y;
        startPointY = newY;
}

this.setDraggable(false);
this.setX(newX);
this.setY(newY);
layer.draw();
this.setDraggable(true);
 return {

x: newX,
y: newY
}   
}
```

Comment: "Advice" is probably too open-ended and opinion-based for StackOverflow.

Comment: Threre's a great asteroids example here https://codepen.io/jscottsmith/pen/qNvAXo?editors=1010 - maybe it could give you some pointers, or at least take your mind off the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have had to choose the easy route this time and just enable stroke when a collision is detected on the dragged shape and then if the user leaves it in that position it is reset to the x and y values saved at dragstart. The problem now is if the shape has been rotated my collision detection code breaks!